# No puede setear un tipo Double en un tipo Class

Tags: java, reflection, genericos

estoy creando una clase generica que me cree un HashMap de los atributos de un objeto y el valor que tiene el atributo en el objeto que se pase. Sin embargo al intentar setear el valor del atributo me arroja el error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Double field rest.MyObject.double1 to java.lang.Class

En este caso la idea es obtener un `HasMap<String, Double>` donde `String` es el nombre del atributo y `Double` el valor almacenado. tengo las siguientes clases

```
public class MyObject {
    private Integer int1;
    private Integer int2;
    private Integer int3;
    private Integer int4;
    private Integer int5;
    private Double double1;
    private Double double2;
    private Double double3;
    private Double double4;
    private Double double5;
    private Double double6;
    private Double double7;
    private Double double8;

    public MyObject(){
        this.int1 = 1;
        this.int2 = 142;
        this.int3 = 2;
        this.int4 = 1;
        this.int5 = 1;
        this.double1 = 9900D;
        this.double2 = 8800D;
        this.double3 = 7700D;
        this.double4 = 6600D;
        this.double5 = 5500D;
        this.double6 = 4400D;
        this.double7  = 3300D;
        this.double8 = 2200D;
    }
    //Getter's Setter's
}
```

Mi clase utilitaria es la siguiente

```
public class UtilObject<T, V> {

    private Class<?> clazz;

    public UtilObject(T clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz.getClass();
    }

    public Map<String, V> getHasMapAttributeValue(Class<V> typeClass) {
        Map<String, V> mapAttributes = new HashMap<>();
        Field[] declaredFields = this.clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        try {
            for (Field field : declaredFields) {
                if (field.getType().getName().equals(typeClass.getName())) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    String attribute = field.getName();
                    V value = typeClass.cast(field.get(this.clazz));
                   mapAttributes.put(attribute, value);
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
            System.out.println(iae.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return mapAttributes;
    }
}
```

Y la implementación la realizo así

```
public class Demos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        UtilObject<MyObject, Double> util = new UtilObject(myObject);
        Map<String, Double> map = util.getHasMapAttributeValue(Double.class);
        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

El error se presenta en la linea

```
 V value = typeClass.cast(field.get(this.clazz));
```

de la clase `UtilObject`  Agradezco de su colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación de Java se especifica que

> If, after possible unwrapping, the new value cannot be converted to
>   the type of the underlying field by an identity or widening
>   conversion, the method throws an IllegalArgumentException.

Así pues, usar un Class sin más esperando que el compilador lo resuelva por reflection no es válido en este caso. Posiblemente ayude no asumir que el campo a obtener es estático y crear primero una instancia nueva de `clazz`

```
Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
```

y luego obtener el valor que buscas con

```
field.get(instance);
```

Sugerencia para revisar sobre este error: [Respuesta en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27663818/236345)

Comment: No, el problema no es ahí, clazz es el objeto que tiene los datos, tiene atributos de tipo `Integer` y atributos de tipo `Double` y deseo hacer un `HashMap` de los atributos `Double` de la forma `{nombreAtributo, valor}` El tema es que de forma generica quiero pasar el tipo de atributos que desee sacar en el mapa, el error se presenta al momento de querer guardar el valor del atributo `Double` en una variable "supuestamente" `Double`